# I got garbled character with ibm_db@2.6.1 in nodejs project

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, db2, loopback, dashdb

I am working on a nodejs project. There is company name 'ABC AEROLÍNEAS SA DE CV' in DB2. While using ibm_db@2.6.1 to get the name, it turned into 'ABC AEROL�NEAS SA DE CV' in my nodejs.

I tried to verify it by using python with ibm_db 3.0.1 and got 'ABC AEROL\xcdNEAS SA DE CV'. I think the '\xcd' should be correct since it displays 'ABC AEROLÍNEAS SA DE CV' in python console. Furthermore, I tested it by JDBC and got the correct name too.

I don't know why nodejs's ibm_db cannot get the correct name. Could someone help to check this? Thanks.

DB
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QuG6.png)

NodeJS
[NodeJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a92gZ.png)

Python
[Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NprFb.png)

Comment: What is the database codepage and the codepage of your Node.js app?

Comment: You are handling non-ASCII strings, hence your code needs to be updated to handle character set encoding, i.e. converting from external encoding (DB) into internal encoding (code) into external encoding (display).

Comment: @StefanBecker The DB connection string doesn't has charset attribution. even I add charset=UTF8, it doesn't work. I also have tried to convert the encoding of the company name, but it didn't get correct result.

Comment: @StefanBecker Oddly, the ibm_db is working to get correct name in Mac, not in Win10. Is it a bug of DB driven?

Answer (score 0):

The hex value `\xCD` is an (extended) ASCII value. In UTF-8 you would need `\xC3\x8D`. In UTF-16 you would need `\x00\xCD`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8D#Character_mappings

Do note that some Windows native programs will display invalid UTF-8 bytes as valid characters, when strictly they should be displaying `�` or similar.

If you use a JDBC based SQL editor, you would see � (or a null value) in your string

Comment: I think the data should be correctly stored in DB2. I checked it with DBevaer. I don't know how to add image here. So add the snapshot link below.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31400781/65174605-cdcf5a00-da83-11e9-8295-eacb617a8211.png

Comment: You can use `HEX()` on the column to see the byte encoding of the column values in SQL

Comment: You can also see the code page of a column via the CODEPAGE column of SYSCAT.COLUMNS

Comment: Use HEX()? like that?
```
SELECT GLOBALITOTID, COMPANY_FULL_NAME, HEX(COMPANY_FULL_NAME)
FROM CEUI.ACCOUNT
WHERE GLOBALITOTID='GB227V69'
```
GLOBALITOTID|COMPANY_FULL_NAME      |3                                               |
------------|-----------------------|------------------------------------------------|
GB227V69    |ABC AEROLÍNEAS SA DE CV|414243204145524F4CC38D4E454153205341204445204356|

Comment: So that C38D is your Í and is perfectly correct UTF-8. So the issue is not how the data is stored in DB2 (assuming this is a 1208 codepage column)

Comment: Yes, someone tells me to check the codepage. I have to contact the DBA to confirm it tomorrow. But, if the data is correct in DB2, then why I got incorrect data by ibm_db? The ibm_db is working to get correct name in Mac, not in Win10. Is it DB driven bug?

Comment: @all

After setting `DB2CODEPAGE=1208`, it works now. Thanks everyone.